# How many features is VGG16 supposed to extract when used as a pre-trained feature extractor?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm using Keras with the TensorFlow backend to extract features from images with a pre-trained model (VGG16 on ImageNet). From what I can read online, I should get for each image a vector with 4096 features.

I'm using this line to import the model without the last fully connected layer (as I believe I'm supposed to):

`applications.vgg16.VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, pooling='avg'`

However, the vector I get in the end only has 512 features. Considering VGG16's architecture:

[image: VGG16's architecture]

It looks like I'm actually getting the results from the last max pooling layer (which would be consistent with the Keras documentation).

So am I supposed to get 512 or 4096 features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Keras documentation](https://keras.io/applications/#vgg16) when you set `include_top = False` it overlooks the last 3 Fully Connected(FC) layers so intuitively you should be getting a 512 feature vector which is correct. If you wish to consider the last 3 FC layers set `include_top = True`. Then you would get a 1000 feature prediction (considering the softmax layer at the end).

Try executing:

```
vggmodel = keras.applications.vgg16.VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, pooling='avg')
vggmodel.summary()
```

and

```
vggmodel = keras.applications.vgg16.VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=True, pooling='avg') 
vggmodel.summary()
```

to get a more comprehensive understanding.