# Reduce vector dimension 4096 -> less than 2000 for Postgres

Tags: python, postgresql, vector, vgg-net, pgvector

I am using Postgresql with pgvector for searching similarity between images. The vector should have up to 2000 dimensions, so that Postgres/pgvector can index it.

I am creating a vector of the image with Python and VGG16/VGG19. As a result, I get a vector with 4096 features/dimensions. I need to reduce it to less than 2000 dimensions using Python.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Even though postgresql/pgvector is why you need to accomplish this, I'm not sure it's actually a _part of the question_ enough to need to be included in the title and tagging. Knowing pgvector doesn't change whether someone can answer this, or whether one answer is more applicable than another.

Comment: Why exactly do you extract a 4096-n vector with VGG models? If you remove the last layer from the model and add a standard pooling layer you should get 512 dimensions. See also this [thread on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56876348/how-many-features-is-vgg16-supposed-to-extract-when-used-as-a-pre-trained-featur?rq=1).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use [Principal Component Analysis](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html) (PCA) to reduce the dimensions of your source vectors.

You can adapt this code (here using random dummy data to illustrate):

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
import numpy as np

vectors_4096 = np.array([np.random.normal(size=4096) for x in range(5000)])
display(vectors_4096.shape)
>>> (5000, 4096)

# instantiate PCA 
# for n_components choose number of dims that you want to reduce to
pca = PCA(n_components=2000)

# fit PCA model and transform data:
vectors_pca = pca.fit_transform(vectors_4096)
display(vectors_pca.shape)
>>> (5000, 2000)
```

Be aware that you have to fit the PCA model once on your corpus and then only use the `transform()` function of the fitted model to new, unseen data (e.g. a couple of new embeddings that you might want to ingest into your PostgreSQL data base). Only this way you make sure that the data transformation for new data is equal to that transformed existing data.